# C - Using malloc, realloc and free. I get too many memory leaks, what's wrong?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

So, my goal was to define a struct in which there is -

1. A command name (e.g. - "print")
2. Command arguments counter
3. A strings array containing the arguments.

You can review my code, but I'm really having a hard time understanding what am I doing wrong -

1. I use malloc to dynamically set my_struct.command size
2. I use malloc to dynamically set my_struct.arguments array size
3. I use realloc to dynamically increase my_struct.arguments size for every argument I set
4. I use malloc to dynamically set my_struct.arguments[i] size
5. I finally call cleanup(), to free any dynamically assigned pointers.

I keep getting LOTS of memory leaks. But I cannot understand why.

Help and tips will be kindly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct  {
    char *command;
    int arguments_count;
    char **arguments;
} my_struct;

void cleanup(void);

int main() {
    int i;

    my_struct.command = (char *)malloc(6*sizeof(char));

    my_struct.command = "print";
    my_struct.arguments_count = 1;
    my_struct.arguments = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));

    my_struct.arguments[0] = "hello";

    for(i = 1 ; i < 10; i++) {
        my_struct.arguments = (char **)realloc(my_struct.arguments, sizeof(char *)*(i+1));
        my_struct.arguments[i] = (char *)malloc(8*sizeof(char));
        my_struct.arguments[i] = "hello";
        my_struct.arguments_count++;
    }

    printf("Arguments count is: %d\n", my_struct.arguments_count);
    printf("The arguments are:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", my_struct.arguments[i]);
    }

    cleanup();

    exit(0);
}

void cleanup(void) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        free(my_struct.arguments[i]);

    free(my_struct.arguments);
    free(my_struct.command);
}
```

Comment: `my_struct.command = (char *)malloc(6*sizeof(char)); my_struct.command = "print";` That right there is a leak!

Comment: And please for the love of god don't use `sizeof(char)`

Comment: `arg[i] = malloc(8*sizeof(char)); arg[i] = "hello";` -- That's a memory leak. You reserve memory, but immediately lose the handle to it by assigning to a string literal. The string literal isn't something you can `free` later, either.

Comment: ```strcpy``` to copy a string to a char array.

Comment: ```strcpy(my_struct.command, "hello");```

Comment: Thank you all for the comments!

Well, even after using strcpy(), I keep getting "XXX bytes are definitely lost in loss record ...' in valgrind.

Comment: `my_struct.arguments[i] = "hello";` You should use strcpy here as well, as you're overwriting the pointer value. At any rate, to better debug your programs, compile with debug symbols (gcc/clang -g) and then run it through valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

> **strdup** - The  strdup()  function  returns  a  pointer  to  a  new
> string which is a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new
> string is obtained with *malloc*, and can be freed with *free*.

```
my_struct.command = strdup("print");

my_struct.arguments_count = 1;
my_struct.arguments = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
my_struct.arguments[0] = strdup("hello");

for (int i=1; i < 10; ++i) {
    // if the number of args is known, allocate before entering the loop
    my_struct.arguments = (char**) realloc(my_struct.arguments, sizeof(char*)*(i+1));
    my_struct.arguments[i] = strdup("hello");
    my_struct.arguments_count++;
}

// in your cleanup use the arguments_count var instead of the literal 10
for (int i=0; i < my_struct.arguments_count; ++i)
```

Your mistake was:

```
// allocate a memory block of 6 bytes
// assign the address of that block to command
my_struct.command = malloc(6);

// then you assigned the address of the string 'print' to command
// therefore the previous allocated block is lost -> mem leak
my_struct.command = "print";

// strdup does the following
return memcpy(malloc(strlen(str) + 1), str, strlen(str) + 1);
```